# Notification when activity is in background mode

Tags: android

I want to show notification when my application is on spacified activity and in background mode.

So i add notification in onPause and clear notification in onResume.

But the problem is when I switch actuvities the notification comes up.

Any advice how to fix it?

Comment: Does the Notification comes up when you switch out of your specified activity, or when you re-enter it?

Comment: @Rajath when I switch out from specified activity.

Comment: Then it's behaving the way you want it to, right?

Comment: @Rajath not realy. Basicly i want to know in my onPause method is application goes to background, or it is new activity comes up.

Comment: And how do you initiate the activity to go into background mode?

Comment: @Rajath  when user press Home button.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to differentiate between `going to the home screen` and `another activity coming up`. Let your notif be shown in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching activities causes onPause() to fire. Technically, switching Activities fulfills your notion of "background mode". Bear in mind that Activities don't really do anything in the background, and that once they're backgrounded they can be destroyed at any moment should the Dalvik VM decide it needs that memory. In other words, there's probably a better way to accomplish what you're after.

Comment: I understand it. It is not a problem for me. Basicly i want to know in my onPause method is application goes to background, or it is new activity comes up.

Comment: There is no difference. Your Activity's onPause() method always gets called whenever the Activity goes from visible to invisible, regardless of the reason. Again, whatever it is you're trying to do can likely be accomplished better in a different way.

Comment: I have a service that works on background and use trafic. So when application is on background mode i want to notify user "hey, application still using your trafic, don't forget." Why onPause method is bad for it?

Comment: Let me be clearer. Activities don't have a "background mode." Activities are only active when in the foreground. Once they're navigated away from they are no longer operational. You can resume them as long as Dalvik hasn't destroyed them, but "backgrounding" them is not possible. If you need background processes, you should look at the Service class.

Comment: Then you're apparently using Services correctly. I think you overestimate the persistence of Activities though. You shouldn't rely on the user to stop the Service. The state of the Service should be managed by the user's apparent behavior. If they leave the Activity and are no longer using your data, stop or pause the service. You can always restart it during onResume(), which is called both when an Activity resumes AND when it's first created.